# custom string format text input wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, string-formatting

I have values that are in format [double-type-value][unit] where unit can be "g" or "mg" (g for grams and mg for milligrams). Is there a way to allow user to enter text in TextBox ONLY in that format. For example to be like mini textbox that accept only numbers and mini combobox where values are "g" or "mg" in normal textbox or something else? It would be nice for unit to have default value to be "g" before something is typed in textbox so user don't have to type g or mg at the end of the textbox everty time if there are more textboxes.

EDIT
I’m using MVVM pattern, so code behind is violating it.

Comment: you can use a Converter for that

Comment: @DenisSchaf if you mean to implement a class that inherits IValueConverter, that will just convert valid value that user typed to format I need. I want to prevent a user from typing anything else except a value in that format.

Comment: in this case you only have one possibility and that is to use the PreviewTextInput event
in this event convert the input text to a double value if the convert fails handle the input event so it is not accepted if the conversion succeeds just exit your function. It makes sanse to create a custom control for that purpose so you can reuse it easily if needed

Comment: Is the Unit-Quantifier relevant for the Code? I mean, how does you Code know if the given value is in mg or g and multiplies/divides the value accordingly (or is this completely irrelevant).

Comment: @LittleBit I have a database and everything in database is recorded in grams. I only use conversion i UI for better user experience. For example user wants to enter 0.01mg, I don’t want him to write 0.00001 every time.

Comment: @Kevin Cook it is okay, but in some cases, user writes values in DataGrid. In that case I can only put I combobox for whole DataGrid, but that is not the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due the nature of this input i suggest you to create a little `CustomControl`, more specific a `TextBox` which is capable of limiting the `Input` and convert the `Text` to the according value -> a `GramTextBox`.

The `GramTextBox` has a `DependencyProperty`called `Gram` which represents the value of the entered `Text` and can be bound to a `ViewModel` (NOTE: The binding must contain `Mode=TwoWay` due the `GramTextBox` tries to update the bound `Source`).

**Code**

```
public sealed class GramTextBox : TextBox
{
    //Constructor
    public GramTextBox() : base()
    {
        Text = "0g"; //Initial value
        TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
        DataObject.AddPastingHandler(this, OnPaste);
    }

    //Style override (get the Style of a TextBox for the GramTextBox)
    static GramTextBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(GramTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TextBox)));
    }

    //Define a DependencyProperty to make it bindable (dont forget 'Mode=TwoWay' due the bound value is updated from this GramTextBox)
    [Category("Common"), Description("Converted double value from the entered Text in gram")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Bindable(true)]
    public double Gram
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(PathDataProperty); }
        set { SetCurrentValue(PathDataProperty, value); }
    }
    public static DependencyProperty PathDataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Gram", typeof(double), typeof(GramTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(0d));

    //Extract the Gram value when Text has changed
    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExtractGram(Text);
    }

    //Suppress space input
    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = e.Key == Key.Space;
    }

    //Check text inputs
    protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !IsValidText(Text.Insert(CaretIndex, e.Text));
    }

    //check paste inputs
    private void OnPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        //Check if pasted object is string
        if(e.SourceDataObject.GetData(typeof(string)) is string text)
        {
            //Check if combined string is valid
           if(!IsValidText(Text.Insert(CaretIndex, text))) { e.CancelCommand(); }
        }
        else { e.CancelCommand(); }
    }

    //Check valid format for extraction (supports incomplete inputs like 0.m -> 0g)
    private bool IsValidText(string text)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^([0-9]*?\.?[0-9]*?m?g?)$");
    }

    //Extract value from entered string
    private void ExtractGram(string text)
    {
        //trim all unwanted characters (only allow 0-9 dots and m or g)
        text = Regex.Replace(text, @"[^0-9\.mg]", String.Empty);
        //Expected Format -> random numbers, dots and couple m/g

        //trim all text after the letter g 
        text = text.Split('g')[0];
        //Expected Format -> random numbers, dots and m

        //trim double dots (only one dot is allowed)
        text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=\..*)(\.)", String.Empty);
        //Expected Format -> random numbers with one or more dots and m

        //Check if m is at the end of the string to indicate milli (g was trimmed earlier)
        bool isMilli = text.EndsWith("m");

        //Remove all m, then only a double number should remain
        text = text.Replace("m", String.Empty);
        //Expected Format -> random numbers with possible dot

        //trim all leading zeros
        text = text.TrimStart(new char[] { '0' });
        //Expected Format -> random numbers with possible dot

        //Check if dot is at the beginning
        if (text.StartsWith(".")) { text = $"0{text}"; }
        //Expected Format -> random numbers with possible dot

        //Check if dot is at the end
        if (text.EndsWith(".")) { text = $"{text}0"; }
        //Expected Format -> random numbers with possible dot

        //Try to convert the remaining String to a Number, if it fails -> 0
        Double.TryParse(text, out double result);

        //Update Gram Property (divide when necessary)
        Gram = (isMilli) ? result / 1000d : result;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

Put this `Class` in `YOURNAMESPACE` and in the `XAML` add a namespace alias

```
xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:YOURNAMESPACE"
```

Now the `GramTextBox` can be used like this

```
<cc:GramTextBox Gram="{Binding VMDoubleProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" ... />
```

it will update the bound `Property` in `ViewModel` every time the `Text` of the `GramTextBox` changes (eg. valid inputs from keyboard/paste etc).

**Notes**

It is intended that nonsense inputs like `.00g`, `0.0m`, `.mg` set the `Gram` `Property` to `0` (like a fallback value).

**Personal Note**

Thanks @Pavel for the `PasteHandler`

**Edit**

To use this `GramTextBox` in a `DataGrid`, you can override the `CellTemplate` of the `Column`:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ... >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
       <!-- Put some other Columns here like DataGridTextColumn -->
       <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Mass">
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <cc:GramTextBox Gram="{Binding VMDoubleProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" ... />
               </DataTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn>
       <!-- Put some other Columns here -->
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Can I use a similar method for datagrid? Because there are some cases when user write data in datagrid?

Comment: @TatjanaCerovic Of course but you have to set it as `CellTemplate` of the `DataGrid` and may define the other `Columns` manually. Details see Edit.

Answer (score 1):

You should actually handle three events:

- `PreviewTextInput`
- `PreviewKeyDown` - to prevent entering whitespace characters, as they are not handled by PreviewTextInput
- `DataObject.Pasting` attached event to prevent user from pasting invalid text from the clipboard

It is better to encapsulate this logic inside a behavior.
A have examples of a similar behaviors: [TextBoxIntegerInputBehavior](https://bitbucket.org/PahanMenski/wpf-training-2015/src/933c754f6ba00f16a44f42b42812ea723d6f8a34/WpfTraining/Lecture07/BlendBehaviors/Behaviors/TextBoxIntegerInputBehavior.cs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), [TextBoxDoubleInputBehavior](https://bitbucket.org/PahanMenski/wpf-training-2015/src/933c754f6ba00f16a44f42b42812ea723d6f8a34/WpfTraining/Lecture07/BlendBehaviors/Behaviors/TextBoxDoubleInputBehavior.cs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression with the events `PreviewTextInput`, `DataObject.Pasting` and `PreviewKeyDown` on a `TextBox` to check if the new string matches a `regex`, if it doesn't you are able to cancel the operation.

Like so:

`xaml`:

```
...
<TextBox PreviewTextInput="txtbox_PreviewTextInput" DataObject.Pasting="txtbox_Pasting" PreviewKeyDown="txtbox_PreviewKeyDown" />
...
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Regex gramOrMilliGramRegex = new Regex("^[0-9.-]+(m?g)?$");

    public MainWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void txtbox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        if(sender is TextBox txtbox)
        {
            string newString = txtbox.Text.Substring(0, txtbox.CaretIndex) + e.Text + txtbox.Text.Substring(txtbox.CaretIndex); //Build the new string
            e.Handled = !gramOrMilliGramRegex.IsMatch(e.Text); //Check if it matches the regex
        }

    }

    private void txtbox_Pasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        if(sender is TextBox txtbox)
        {
            string newString = txtbox.Text.Substring(0, txtbox.CaretIndex) + e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(string)) as string + txtbox.Text.Substring(txtbox.CaretIndex); //Build new string
            if (!digitOnlyRegex.IsMatch(newString)) //Check if it matches the regex
            {
                e.CancelCommand();
            }
        }

    private void txtbox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //Prevents whitespace
        if (e.Key == Key.Space)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

UPDATE: As you now mention you are using MVVM and don't want to violate the pattern.

You will need to route these events to commands in your `ViewModel`, and place the events above there.

You can do this by using this code in your `TextBox` in the xaml:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:cmd ="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"

...

<TextBox>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewTextInput">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=PreviewTextInputCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="DataObject.Pasting">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=DataObject_PastingCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=PreviewKeyDownCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: This violates MVVM pattern, which I said I’m using it in comments. I edited post now

Comment: @TatjanaCerovic Updated so it can be implemented without violating the MVVM pattern.

Comment: @Alfie Routing commands to modiyfy your gui to a your ViewModel will still violate the MVVM pattern even though the code behind stays empty...

Comment: @TatjanaCerovic to be honest, I think the original solution is totally fine in regards to MVVM, its the views job to handle user input and interact with the viewmodel, so validation of user input is the view's responsibility and doesn't break the MVVM pattern. This a bit of an arbitrary subject however, there is no wrong or right answer here, I do not want to start a debate, just my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

To prevent users from entering anything but numbers you have to use the PrevieTextInput event it makes sense to create a custom control for that. The few lines below will keep the user from entering anything but numbers

```
    <Grid>            
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,0">g</TextBlock>
    </Grid>


    private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = sender as TextBox;
        e.Handled = !double.TryParse(tb.Text+e.Text, out double d);
    }
```

P.S. if you dont like the use of the try Catch you can use a regex for that

Comment: She should use a Regex as she wants to allow strings like "105g" or "11mg" if I understand correctly.

Comment: i dont think she want to have a "g" in the actual string that would make furter processing unessarily difficult i guess she want to show its gram or mg. That could be easily achived by overlaing a textblock (edited my answer)

Comment: Does this violates MVVM pattern, because I'm using it?

Comment: it does indeed violate the MVVM pattern if you do it in the code behind!
But to achive your goal there is simply no other way to prevent user input.
 That is why i recommended to create a custom control so that this does not conflict with the MVVM pattern of you project
I personally work with the MVVM pattern as well but use eventhandlers in my custom controls sometimes as MVVM has its limitations

Comment: It does **not** violate MVVM if you write a control/template which allows only specific input. In fact you could implement it as a behaviour textboxes.

Comment: @jaster could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Additionally, i recommend you take a closer look at the used `Event`. For example, the `PreviewTextInput` does not prevent malformed `strings` when you paste something into the `TextBox`. And please do not use this `Try/catch` pattern to check something when there is a specific Method for the Conversion -> `Double.TryParse()`.

Comment: @Danis Schaf I acctually want from user to input unit (for example 5.653mg) and then convert that string into double value in grams. I don’t know if there is a better approach for this but I just want to simplify user to input 5.653mg instead of 0.00563g

Comment: You should additionally handle PreviewKeyDown event, because PreviewTextInput is not fired on whitespace characters input. And you should also handle DataObject.Pasting attached event to prevent user from pasting invalid text from the keyboard.

Comment: @LittleBit Tahnks! i didnt knew about tryparse!